# 3v output to switch on transistor for 5v fan

Tags: arduino, transistors, raspberry-pi, npn

Im having trouble selecting resistors for my circuit. I have a 5v supply and my wemos board has a digital pin output of 3v.

I want to use the wemos output pin to switch a transistor (BC547) on to power my 5v fan. Without resistors im only getting 2.5 which is odd as i definitely have 5v at the transistor collector.

[image]

Comment: Put the fan (with a fly-back diode) in the collector connection, connect the emitter directly to ground. I am not providing an answer as I am sure this has come up before in previous question(s) but I can't find them so quickly.

Comment: Thank you, its so obvious now you've said it that i'm a little embarrassed I didn't think of it.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you have configured your output transistor as an "emitter follower". In this mode the emitter voltage will follow the base voltage less about 0.6 to 0.7 V drop due to the base-emitter voltage drop. This matches what you are seeing.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frrR6j.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) Emitter follower. (b) Load in the collector.*

With configuration (b) the GPIO will turn Q2 on to saturation. The collector voltage will drop to about 0.2 V giving 4.8 V to the motor. D1 protects the transistor from inductive spikes when the transistor is turned off.

Answer (score 1):

Your circuit is not good. You are driving the fan [common collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_collector) which means the fan can only get Vb - 0.7V = 2.3V if the base drive is 3V. What you are observing is expected behaviour.

You want [common emitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_emitter). This will allow the fan to get the full 5V available if the transistor saturates on. You might also want a resistor from base to ground to keep the transistor off if the logic output is undefined for an instant at switch on or whatever.